# How to specify options to Custom Formatter in Accumulo

Tags: accumulo

I am planning to use same formatter for different accumulo tables with one configurable option.

Is it possible to provide options to Custom Formatter in accumulo? I tried using OptionDescriber but it seems that OptionDescriber gets invoked only during setiterator command.

Or at least is there any way to get current table properties (on which table the custom fomatter is set). I mean if the formatter was set on TABLE_A, then formatter code should be able to load all the table properties during initialization. So that I can set the required properties to table using "config" and the custom formatter can access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to set options directly on the formatter in the shell. If your custom formatter needs to accept options, you'll have to write your formatter so that it accepts options outside of Accumulo, for example by reading java system properties you set in the environment, or by reading a configuration file stored locally on your system.